# How do I attach values to a variable from multiple cells without combining them?

Tags: excel

I'm creating a macro tracker and would like to create a variable that when used would be able to give information back into different cells. for instance, I call the variable in A1 then the values come up in A3, A4, A5, and A6. it would make the spreadsheet much more clean if I could find a solution, but I seem to be stuck. any help is very appreciated.

haven't figured out a solution.

Comment: There are two ways to do what you want: you put the formula `=A1` in cells "A3", "A4", "A5" and "A6". If you just want to put one formula in cell "A3" and drag it to the next rows, you might need to modify your formula into `=A$1`. The second way is to write a VBA macro for filling in the values.